# Уменьшить время зачисления с 24 часов до 5 минут

Tags: javascript

есть код, в котором зачисление энной единицы с энного элемента происходит в процентной ставке раз в 24 часа, как сделать так, что бы зачисление происходило каждые 5 минут например??. Спасибо!
Сам отрывок кода.

```js
foreach ($cards as $key => $value)
  {
   if($value['valid_date'] > time())
   {
    $period = time() - $value['last_update_money'];
    $days = floor($period / (3600 * 24));
    // $days = 2;
    if($days > 0)
    {
     $percent_per_day = $value->card['procent'] / 30;
     $money_per_day = ($percent_per_day * $value->card['money']) / 100;
     
     $money = $money_per_day * $days;

     if(time() < strtotime('28.12.2017') || time() > strtotime('09.01.2018') || $value['card_id'] == 23 || $value['card_id'] == 24)
     {
      $new_money = $value['money'] + $money;

      if($user->isValid())
       $value['money'] = $new_money;
      else
       $new_money = $value['money'];
     }
     else
     {
      $new_money = $value['money'];
     }

     $value['last_update_money'] += $days * 3600 * 24;
     $value->update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

строка

```
$value['last_update_money'] += $days * 3600 * 24;
```

`3600 * 24` это и есть 24 часа (3600 секунд в часе)

Поменяй на

```
$value['last_update_money'] += $days * 300; // 5 минут - 300 секунд
```

Со строкой

```
$days = floor($period / (3600 * 24));
```

то же самое